# Why can't validate a column in DataGridView only alphabet?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, validation, datagridview

i am doing a project on window form in c# 
i have a DataGridView with data from the database

now i want to do editing in data GridView, and i have this column call Name, but and i want to validate so that when user edit, it will only key in alphabet, like example, in the Name column row 1 has a name call Rosy Chin, then user edit to this Rosy Ch11n ...it should prompt the user say that only alphabet,  i use the code below but it don't prompt me that message...however if the user edit to this 4Rosy Chin....it will appear the prompt message...can i know where am i wrong??

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
    {
        //int indicator;
        int newInteger;

        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) return;
            String data = e.FormattedValue.ToString();

             String validate= @"^[a-zA-Z]";
             Regex nameAlphabet = new Regex(validate);
             String nameGridView = data;                 
             if(!(nameAlphabet.IsMatch(nameGridView )))
             {
                 e.Cancel = true;
                 MessageBox.Show(@"Name must be in Alphabet!");
             }
             else
                 return;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to fix your RegEx:

```
 ^[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

Description:

```
^ start of line
[a-zA-Z ] any letter or space
+ one or more
$ end of line
```

Good RegEx [sandbox](http://www.rubular.com/r/yuBAqG5iOM).

---

To not allow only s space:

```
^[A-Za-z][a-zA-Z ]+[A-Za-z]$
```

Link to the [sandbox](http://www.rubular.com/r/M6T6W9hsOx).

Comment: @abatishchew i not good in regex do you mind telling me the regex what should i change it to??

Comment: @Cute: Yes, change your expression to my, and test

Comment: @abatishchew...where is the open inverted comma?? and the @ ?? and yours is it something similiar to the answer below??

Comment: @Cute: `@"any string"` is used for escaping, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx). What inverted comma you're asking about?

Comment: @abatishchew there a problem again...i try to press spacing...for the name...it still let me go through ...so how should i change it

Comment: abatishchev : What he need is text box should start with an alphabet and the text should contain only a space.

Answer (score 0):

If not try as per below

```
Regex nameAlphabet = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z\s]+$");
```

You can do it pro-grammatically by checking the number of spaces in the text box if space is greater than `1` or if the text box starts with an empty space you can raise the necessary message box you required

try this in your code where you validate

```
  int cnt = 0;
    while (TextBox1.Text.Contains(" "))
    {
        cnt++;
        if (cnt > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.show("Only a space is allowed");
            break;
        }
    }
```

In similar way you can test whether the `textbox` starts with a space or not as follows

```
if(textbox.text.startswith(" "))
{
    // Your message
 }
```

Comment: @Dorababu...i try to use your code, but the problem is no matter is i type in the Rosy Ch4n or Rosy Ch4n...it still prompt me...so how??

Comment: Edited the answer try as per i posted

Comment: there a problem again...i try to press spacing...for the name...it still let me go through ...so how should i change it

Comment: What's the input that you had given

Comment: instead of Rosy Chin....i use spacing to replace it... bt it still go through it dont validate

Comment: You asked that it should accept space and Alphabets so this will validate even if you left the white space

Comment: oh so there no way to prevent it everything becoming white space??